# Why null value enter in database when data entering from dynamic textbox

Tags: jsp, oracle11g

I tried to insert value in database dynamically value enter in database but as null not understanding where is stuck also attaching images for better understand previously value was not inserted but after changes in html page value inserting but as null so not understanding why value inserted null or problem is request.parameter values?

Here is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

      
<script>
function getinput()
{
var employee_id="<br>Employee_id : <input type='text' name='txt_employeeid'>";
var Project_name=" Project_name : <input type='text' name='txt_project_name'>";
var Header=" Header : <input type='text' name='txt_Header'>";
var Department=" Department : <input type='text' name='txt_Department'>";
var Description=" Department : <input type='text' name='txt_description'>";
$("#inputs").append(employee_id,Project_name,Header,Department,Description);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
     
<div id="inputs" align="left">
   
    <button onclick="getinput()">Add</button><br>
</div>
   
    <input type="hidden" name="txtemployeeid" value="employee_id"><br>
    <form action="EmployeeVendorValidation.jsp" method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit"/><br><br>
     </form>
</body>

</html>

My jsp where i tried to enter details in database:
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
                <title>JSP Page</title>
            </head>
            <body>
           <%
     String sbm=request.getParameter("btnSubmit");
           
           String employee_id=request.getParameter("employee_id");
           String txt_project_name=request.getParameter("Project_name");
           String get_header=request.getParameter("Header");
           String get_department=request.getParameter("Department");
           String get_description=request.getParameter("Description");  
           
        if(sbm!=null)
        {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                  Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@173.18.114.213:1821:godb","xe","Spacess");
                  PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into Employee_task values(?,?,?,?,?)");
                  ps.setString(1, employee_id);
                  ps.setString(2, txt_project_name);
                  ps.setString(3, get_header);
                  ps.setString(4, get_department);
                  ps.setString(5, get_description);
                  ps.executeUpdate();
                  out.print("data inserted");
 }
           %>
            </body>
        </html>

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is also similar to your previous question.

In your html code,the parameter names are all start with `text`:

```
var employee_id="<br>Employee_id : <input type='text' name='txt_employeeid'>";
var Project_name=" Project_name : <input type='text' name='txt_project_name'>";
var Header=" Header : <input type='text' name='txt_Header'>";
var Department=" Department : <input type='text' name='txt_Department'>";
var Description=" Department : <input type='text' name='txt_description'>";
```

However in your jsp code when you get the parameter,the parameter name not keep the same:

```
String employee_id=request.getParameter("employee_id");
String txt_project_name=request.getParameter("Project_name");
String get_header=request.getParameter("Header");
String get_department=request.getParameter("Department");
String get_description=request.getParameter("Description");
```

In order to let it work,you need to keep the parameter name the same,change them to below:

```
String employee_id=request.getParameter("txt_employeeid");
String txt_project_name=request.getParameter("txt_project_name");
String get_header=request.getParameter("txt_Header");
String get_department=request.getParameter("txt_Department");
String get_description=request.getParameter("txt_description");
```

---

You also need to change your html code design

```
$("#inputs").append(employee_id,Project_name,Header,Department,Description);
```

The code above is add element to inputs but inside to the `form`,so the value will always be null.

```
<div id="inputs" align="left"> <!-- add element to this div will not inside the form -->

    <button onclick="getinput()">Add</button><br>
</div>

    <input type="hidden" name="txtemployeeid" value="employee_id"><br>
    <form action="EmployeeVendorValidation.jsp" method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit"/><br><br>
     </form>
```

Since you not know how to do it,yo can do with below,now it should work:

change `append` to `html`:

```
$("#inputs").html(employee_id,Project_name,Header,Department,Description);
```

redesign your html page as below:

```
<form action="EmployeeVendorValidation.jsp" method="post">
     <div id="inputs" align="left"></div>
     <input type="hidden" name="txtemployeeid" value="employee_id"><br>
     <button onclick="getinput()">Add</button><br>
     <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit"/><br><br>
 </form>
```

Comment: i changed it but stil null value coming

Comment: no bro same issue employee_id:null i written this in  out.println("employee_id"+employee_id);

Comment: sorry brother but iam not understand solution

Comment: <!-- add element to this div will not inside the form -->
means which element? and how?

Comment: hey,please not call me brother,I felt uncomfortable for it

Comment: ok @lucumt i tried by putting element inside div but still null only showing

Comment: I have updated my answer,if you still do not know how to do it ,then I have no idea

Comment: when i clicking Add button all textboxes disappear quickly

Comment: hey,are you there?

Comment: come to chat box https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169099/discussion-between-lucumt-and-aties

Comment: i tried your suggestion but when i click add button as soon as textboxes show and quickly disappear